# (Done) Reopen "How do companies with blogs make writing happen"

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[How do companies with blogs make writing happen?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/122091/how-do-companies-with-blogs-make-writing-happen)

This question needs another reopen vote. It is not at all "too broad".

Answer (score 3):

> This question needs another reopen vote. It is not at all "too broad".

Casted the final vote and it is open again.